# Average times of tossing two consecutive **Head**s of fair coin?

Tags: probability

What is the average times of tossing a fair coin *until* occuring two consecutive **Head**s ? And what is the average times of tossing an unfair coin with $\frac{1}{3}$ **Head** and $\frac{2}{3}$ **Tail** occuring three consecutive **Head**s? I have thought about it for one hours, but cannot find a way to solve it. Need help.

Comment: Would you please care to clarify further? What is the meaning of average times of tossing two consecutive heads? Surely you meant "The number of times twoconsecutive heads turns up" in two tosses of a fair coin?

Comment: Do you mean *until* you throw two/three consecutive heads? Or do you want to count the expected number of occurrences of two/three consecutive heads in a sequence of a given length?

Comment: Yes, "until" semantics! Edited! @IshraaqParvez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question's language it seems like you need expected number of tosses to achieve **HH**.

Concept to be used: **MARKOV CHAIN**

**PART 1:** Suppose, $t_H$ is time/tosses needed when you received Heads in last toss. Similarly, $t_T$ & $t_{HH}$ denote time/tosses needed from position of Tails or Double heads to reach HH.

Clearly, $t_{HH} = 0$

Now, we can go from state T to either H or T with 0.5 probability each.

Thus, $t_T = 0.5*(t_T+1) + 0.5*(t_H+1) = 0.5*(t_T+t_H)+1$

Again, we can go from state H to HH(destination) or T(reset point for HH path) with 0.5 probability each.

Thus, $t_H = 0.5*(t_T +2) + 0.5(t_{HH}+1)= 0.5*t_T + 1$

On, solving we get $t_H = 4$ & $t_T=6$

Thus, from reset point or **T** tosses/time = $t_T$ = 6

**PART 2:** Now, consider states as **T**, **H**, **HH**, **HHH**

$$t_T = (1-p)*t_T+p*t_H+1$$
$$t_H = (1-p)*t_T+p*t_{HH}+1$$
$$t_{HH}=(1-p)*t_T+p*t_{HHH}+1$$

where p = Prob. of getting a head = $\frac{1}{3}; $ $t_{HHH}=0$ and $t_T$ is required answer from rest state.

On solving $t_T=63$

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic stopping time question. Let $\tau$ be the the first time you see consecutive two heads in a sequence of heads and tails $X_1, X_2, ...$, where $X_i$ is a binary variable with values $H$ or $T$. $\tau$ is given by
$$
\tau = \min\{n: X_n=X_{n-1}=H\}.
$$
We want to find $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$. We use conditional probability for this purpose,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[\tau] &= 1/2 \times \mathbb{E}[\tau | X_1=H] + 1/2 \times \mathbb{E}[\tau | X_1=T]\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now the trick is to observe that $\mathbb{E}[\tau | X_1=T] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[\tau]$ (since $X_1=T$ in this case, so we have 1 step for sure, and then we start over again to reach the stopping time, which happens in $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ steps), and
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[\tau | X_1=H] &= 1/2 \times \mathbb{E}[\tau | X_1=H, X_2=H] + 1/2 \times \mathbb{E}[\tau | X_1=H, X_2=T]\\
&= 1/2 \times 2 + 1/2 \times (2+\mathbb{E}[\tau])\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This yields
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau] = 1/2 \times ( 1 + 1/2 \times (2+\mathbb{E}[\tau])) + 1/2 \times (1+\mathbb{E}[\tau])
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau] = 6
$$

Same reasoning applies to the second question.

N.B: please re-check calculations as I have gone through very quickly.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{E}[\tau]=6$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_H$ be the expected number of additional tosses needed if the last toss was heads.

Let $a_T$ be the expected number of additional tosses needed if the last toss was not heads.  This includes both the case where the last toss was tails, and the case where we haven't made any tosses yet.  So, if we can compute $a_T$ we are done.

We have $$\begin{align}
a_T&=\frac23(1+a_T)+\frac13(1+a_H)\\
a_H&=\frac13+\frac23(1+a_T)
\end{align}$$